# Navigation Menu Dropdowns Stuck Behind Other Elements

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, css-float

I'm having what I believe to be a simple problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. 
Basically, while hovering over links on the menu, the drop-down menus "go behind" the other elements on my page. I've tried implementing float css but it doesn't seem to work.
If you visit my site just for a second and hover on the navigation menu you'll see what I mean.
How do you fix something like this?
Will appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, the site is: http://www.runaroundnetwork.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, set your `z-index` to a really big number like `9005`, so it's above everything else on the page.

Like: `z-index: 9005;`

Comment: Ok, just tried that- even put it up to 9999 and 99999999 but didn't work. :(

Comment: Are you sure you did that for the right thing? Make sure you set it for the hover elements of the nav bar.

Comment: I think- does the z-index go in the #menu-bar css?

Comment: set your #page-bar to do that, i just tried it just now and it worked. Take a look: http://f.cl.ly/items/0o053J0g3T0a321n3I2u/Screen%20shot%202012-12-01%20at%2011.33.04%20AM.png

Comment: Ah ok, for some reason I was thinking of the menu-bar css instead of the ones of the dropdown menus. Thank you! The screenshot really helped!

Answer (score 1):

add `z-index:9999;` to the `#page-bar` css
it solves the problem (tested in chrome)